# Is MMSE the right site for asking materials science questions?

Tags: discussion, on-topic, questions

I am Materials science Ph.D. student. I just want to know is it the right site I am in to ask my question related to materials science related field?

Comment: From the *Tour*: "Matter Modeling Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for Matter Modelers: computational chemists, material scientists, particle physicists, data scientists, and anyone else who uses computational methods to study molecules and materials."       If you find yourself as one of those mentioned above then this is the right site to ask your questions.

Comment: @Sha we migrated this to Meta, so you can turn your comment into an answer now :) That's what I did!

Comment: @NikeDattani perfect! You make us all look good.

Answer (score 5):

You can ask it here. We will try our best to help get your question answered, and if we think that the Engineering Stack Exchange (or Chemistry Stack Exchange, or Computational Science Stack Exchange, or Physics Stack Exchange, etc.) users will be more likely to be able to help you quickly, then we'll migrate the question there for you!

Answer (score 3):

As Nike Dattani [suggests](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/373/201), go ahead and post a question, or add further details about the question(s) you'd like to ask in the main site back into your question here in meta.

This is a particularly friendly and helpful SE community so either way folks will help you sort things out by either recommending additional information to add to (or remove from) your question and/or perhaps closing it and staring the process to migrate it to a different SE site.

There are [almost 200 SE sites to choose from](https://stackexchange.com/sites#percentanswered)! But they vary in question rate and temperament. For example, [your first question in Physics SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/729223/83380)<sup>1</sup> received no answers and was quick-closed by only three users (rather than the traditional five). Although it's a perfectly reasonable question, those folks don't handle practical questions about doing physics very well. They like questions that look more like problem-solving, or sometimes history. But questions requiring specific knowledge of certain techniques are often closed by folks who if they can't answer it themselves may think the question has no right to be there<sup>2</sup>.

Basically Physics SE is too big<sup>3,4</sup> and the question rate is way too high to work as a proper Stack Exchange community. You can still get answers there but you need to develop a nose for what will pique enough people's interest that they don't just close it arbitrarily.

Here are some examples of questions that I've asked here that while not *directly asking* about modeling (numerical or otherwise) are thinks you'd need to know or understand to do so.

- [What does capital sigma followed by an integer (Σn) mean in the context of grain boundaries?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/2131/201)
- [Analytical expression for an atomic lattice "muffin-tin" potential for purposes of illustration and simple scattering calculations](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/3862/201)
- [Quantum mechanical antireflection coating; what quantity would be analogous to index of refraction?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/6920/201)
- [Straightforward formalism to get four sets of 2D hexagonal lattice vectors of fcc(111) planes that I can also cite?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/6364/201)
- [Proposing a 2D quasicrystal; what are the necessary and sufficient conditions? (If it looks like a duck and quacks like a duck, or...?)](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/6993/201)
- [Can the color of gold metal be reproduced by modeling only the conduction electron band structure, or do atomic absorption lines contribute?](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/6189/201)

---

- <sup>1</sup>You could edit the question, follow all the instructions in comments there, and perhaps even include a snapshot of your spectrum, perhaps with an arrow pointing to the small peak in question. Editing may trigger a review of the question and start the reopen process. I have followed the question so that I'll get a notification when there's been activity there and can try to help further if you decide to do that.
- <sup>2</sup>in my opinion/experience
- <sup>3</sup>[this answer to *Why was a question manually removed from hot network questions?*](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14060/83380) in Physics SE meta
- <sup>4</sup>[this answer to *How to Help the Physics.SE grow (member-wise)? Qualitatively as well as Quantitatively*](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/12734/83380) in Physics SE meta